# How to bypass country restriction on some apps like HelloTalk?

Tags: applications, geolocation

Some apps like HelloTalk and Tandem are restricted in Nigeria, and the restrictions of those apps even overpower VPN.

I use Windscribe VPN with paid features I make sure the VPN has no leak because it's always turned on. Yet, the app still detects it and I can't register HelloTalk and Tandem app.

What should I do to bypass it?

Comment: The apps possibly inquiry your device location using GPS/location services instead of IP address.

Answer (score 2):

Apps can use information from your carrier, location of cell tower and the GPS to figure out where you are.  I can get most apps to work this way.

1. Create a Google account

   - Add a payment method with an address in a supported country.
   - You may have to add a different credit card to this account (I havent created one for a while)
2. Add it to your phone
3. Either use this account all the time, or switch accounts when you want to use this app.
4. Turn the VPN on.
5. If it doesn't work, try with GPS turned off.
6. If it still doesnt work, turn of `Wifi scanning` and `Bluetooth scanning` under Location services

---

This still works for me for foreign banking apps and lotto sites.

If the App is using the carrier or your Country has collaborated with the your Carrier to disable these apps, then these apps may still not work.